# Node dissapears when scaling in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I´m loading a model from libgdx and then trying to scale on of the nodes. The model show correctly until I scale the node. The scaling of the entire model works fine.

this is my code:

```
UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
Model model;
model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("crane.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
modelInstance.transform.scale(0.05f,0.05f,0.05f);
modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
System.out.println("Cargado crane exitosamente");
crane.modelInstance.getNode("cuerda_mover").localTransform.scale(0,1.05f,0);
crane.modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
```

The problem is that when I do the transform. The part of the model just dissapears and does not scale as expected.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Dumb mistake. I just needed to change the 0 values in my scale method to 1.

```
crane.modelInstance.getNode("cuerda_mover").localTransform.scale(1,1.05f,1);
```